# Not able to Click on context Menu - Open link in new window in selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mot4d.png)**Right click is working but not able to click on Open link in new window option. **

```
public static void newwindow() throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\Users\\TechExtensor\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/browser/windows/");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement elementLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main_navbar\"]/ul/li[3]/a/span"));
        actions.moveToElement(elementLocator);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
actions.contextClick(elementLocator).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do there and what is not working?

Comment: I want to click on "Open link in new window" from context menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Robot class.

```
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    WebElement elementLocator = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main_navbar\"]/ul/li[3]/a/span"));
    actions.contextClick(elementLocator).perform();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```